# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'key' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, file, encryption

I am trying to import a text file and encrypt/decrypt by two key words. I set a key variable but can't find the correct place to locate it.

Here is where it currently is:

```
def importFile():
     importText = []
     file = input('What is the text file name: ')
     fileName = open(file,'r')
     text = fileName.read()
     fileName.close()
     fileName = text
     message = text
     #print (text)
     delete = open(file,'w')
     delete.write('')
     key = input ('What key do you wnat to use: ')
```

Here is where the `key` is called:

```
def translatedMessage(mode):
    translated = []
    keyIndex = 0
    key = key.upper()

    for symbol in message: 
        num =LETTERS .find(symbol.upper())
        if num != -1: 
            if mode == 'encrypt':
                num += LETTERS .find(key[keyIndex]) 
            elif mode == 'decrypt':
                num -= LETTERS .find(key[keyIndex])

            num %= len(LETTERS)

            if symbol.isupper():
                translated.append(LETTERS[num])
            elif symbol.islower():
                translated.append(LETTERS[num].lower())

            keyIndex += 1 
            if keyIndex == len(key):
                keyIndex = 0
        else:
            translated.append(symbol)
    return ''.join(translated)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you need it here is it all together:

```
LETTERS = 'ZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY'
def main():
    myMode = input("Encrypt 'e' or Decrypt 'd': ")
    if myMode == 'encrypt' or myMode == 'e':
        translated = encryptFile()
    elif myMode == 'decrypt' or myMode == 'd':
        translated = decryptFile()

def importFile():
     importText = []
     file = input('What is the text file name: ')
     fileName = open(file,'r')
     text = fileName.read()
     fileName.close()
     fileName = text
     message = text
     #print (text)
     delete = open(file,'w')
     delete.write('')
     key = input ('What key do you wnat to use: ')

def encryptFile():
    textFile = input("Would you like to import a text file 'Y' or 'N': ")
    if textFile.lower() == 'y' :
        importFile()

    return translatedMessage('encrypt')

def decryptFile():
    textFile = input("Would you like to import a text file 'Y' or 'N': ")
    if textFile.lower() == 'y' :
        importFile()

    return translatedMessage('decrypt')

def translatedMessage(mode):
    translated = []
    keyIndex = 0
    key = key.upper()

    for symbol in message: 
        num =LETTERS .find(symbol.upper())
        if num != -1: 
            if mode == 'encrypt':
                num += LETTERS .find(key[keyIndex]) 
            elif mode == 'decrypt':
                num -= LETTERS .find(key[keyIndex])

            num %= len(LETTERS)

            if symbol.isupper():
                translated.append(LETTERS[num])
            elif symbol.islower():
                translated.append(LETTERS[num].lower())

            keyIndex += 1 
            if keyIndex == len(key):
                keyIndex = 0
        else:
            translated.append(symbol)
    return ''.join(translated)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm pretty new to coding and know this is pretty simple so any advice is greatly appreciated:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are treating `key` like a global variable, but it is a local one, so you need to pass it between your functions:

```
LETTERS = 'ZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY'
def main():
    myMode = input("Encrypt 'e' or Decrypt 'd': ")
    if myMode == 'encrypt' or myMode == 'e':
        translated = encryptFile()
    elif myMode == 'decrypt' or myMode == 'd':
        translated = decryptFile()

def importFile():
     importText = []
     file = input('What is the text file name: ')
     fileName = open(file,'r')
     text = fileName.read()
     fileName.close()
     fileName = text
     message = text
     #print (text)
     delete = open(file,'w')
     delete.write('')
     return input ('What key do you wnat to use: ')  # Return the key

def encryptFile():
    textFile = input("Would you like to import a text file 'Y' or 'N': ")
    if textFile.lower() == 'y' :
        key = importFile()  # Get the key returned by the function

    return translatedMessage('encrypt', key)  # Pass the key to the function

def decryptFile():
    textFile = input("Would you like to import a text file 'Y' or 'N': ")
    if textFile.lower() == 'y' :
        key = importFile()  # Get the key returned by the function

    return translatedMessage('decrypt', key)  # Pass the key to the function

def translatedMessage(mode, key):  # `key` is an argument
    translated = []
    keyIndex = 0
    key = key.upper()

    for symbol in message: 
        num =LETTERS .find(symbol.upper())
        if num != -1: 
            if mode == 'encrypt':
                num += LETTERS .find(key[keyIndex]) 
            elif mode == 'decrypt':
                num -= LETTERS .find(key[keyIndex])

            num %= len(LETTERS)

            if symbol.isupper():
                translated.append(LETTERS[num])
            elif symbol.islower():
                translated.append(LETTERS[num].lower())

            keyIndex += 1 
            if keyIndex == len(key):
                keyIndex = 0
        else:
            translated.append(symbol)
    return ''.join(translated)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

A simpler solution would be to define `key` as a global variable by adding the line `global key` to the `importFile()` function. In general however, I think using the `global` keyword in Python is discouraged.

This explanation of global vs. local variables in Python might be helpful: http://www.python-course.eu/global_vs_local_variables.php